How can the quality of "something being very improbable" be used as a philosophical argument?
Do you understand Marcelo Gleiser's "colossal waste of time" reasoning?

Physicist Marcelo Gleiser objects to the notion that posthumans would
have a reason to run simulated universes: "...being so advanced they
would have collected enough knowledge about their past to have little
interest in this kind of simulation. ...They may have virtual-reality
museums, where they could go and experience the lives and tribulations
of their ancestors. But a full-fledged, resource-consuming simulation
of an entire universe? Sounds like a colossal waste of time." Gleiser
also points out that there is no plausible reason to stop at one level
of simulation, so that the simulated ancestors might also be
simulating their ancestors, and so on, creating an infinite regress
akin to the "problem of the First Cause".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis

I did have a different impression, that in philosophy, even extremely remote possibilities will never be rounded to a zero value.
For example, I accept this argument:

It is possible that consciousness requires a vital substrate that a
computer cannot provide and that simulated people, while behaving
appropriately, would be philosophical zombies. This would undermine
Nick Bostrom's simulation argument; humans cannot be a simulated
consciousness, if consciousness, as humans understand it, cannot be
simulated.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

My 0.1 cent.
Assuming we live in a simulation, the "waste of time" argument is flawed since our time unit can be vastly different than the real time unit, ie 1 billion years our time may simply correspond to 1 second real time (outside simulation).
However the simulation hypothesis is flawed itself. Arguments why simulation hypothesis is flawed:
A. It assumes a perfect simulation but at least according to known laws (eg thermodynamics) such perfect simulation cannot exist physically, the underlying mechanism cannot completely hide itself. A simulation cannot block (the true) physical laws from holding even inside the simulation, so our known laws necessarily must reflect true laws. If a simulation can completely hide its underlying mechanism and block the underlying physical laws from applying inside it, then it is not a simulation anymore, it is rather a separate and complete universe/reality by itself. Similarly, an imperfect simulation cannot give the impression of a valid alternative perceived reality, to the conscious sims inside, because in such a case it would completely hide the underlying mechanism of the actual reality which is impossible for an imperfect simulation. So, if the simulation is imperfect then we can find out or would have already found out in principle thus the argument is undermined.
B. The simulation makers either want us to know we are simulated or not. If they want us to know, then we know it, which we don't. If they don't want us to know then they have to design such system so that it is impossible to betray it is a simulation. The only way to do that is for the system to be the real thing (see perfect simulation above). Either we do not live in a simulation else we would already know it.

I would say that black and white, a perfect or not perfect simulation, would be too crude to assess the chances that we live in simulated reality. There are levels of perfection and the fact that for the last 60 years we did not find anything smaller than quarks could point to the limit of resolution (number of pixels) in our simulator.

If the simulation is imperfect then we can eventually find out since the underlying mechanism cannot be hidden completely. And we can know any simulation must necessarily be imperfect through known laws which necessarily must be a reflection of true laws  (since the true laws cannot be blocked from holding even inside the simulation).

Every simulation has to end, at some point. The condition(s) for ending the simulation run would be built in. Our reality could be a re-run of the previously aborted simulation with some conditional tweaks. When you go into digital format (including post-humans) anything is possible.

The takeaway of the argument is that no simulation can disguise itself as reality, either it will be found out  else it would have to be the real thing. As such a simulation cannot do anything conceivable, for example it cannot make a contradiction true, because then it could not simulate anything. Similarly it cannot hide the true physical laws, they must somehow be reflected in the simulation and through these we know that simulation cannot be perfect and thus find out.

Yes, I do understand the "colossal waste of time" reasoning. So far, the simulation we live in- assuming we live in one- seems to have been running for more than thirteen billion years, which seems a colossal waste of anyone's time.
How do you suppose the simulators are monitoring their simulation? Is it streaming in real time, or do they come back every billion years or so to see how it is getting on? Or maybe they are more advanced than that, and they have monitoring bots reporting on key events. Interesting to speculate on how they are programmed- what criteria they use to determine which events are report-worthy.
In addition to the "colossal waste of time" argument, I incline favourably to the "colossal waste of resources" argument, since a simulation supposedly intended to focus on us humans extends to a Universe so large that we cannot ever see all of it. I would have supposed a vast intelligence would have programmed a more efficient model.
"Something being very improbable" can sometimes mean something being utterly implausible nonsense presented without a shred of evidence or supporting detail.

Is it really any more of a colossal waste of time than positing the existence of god? If not, then why does philosophy not consider that a colossal waste of time just as much as many do for the idea that we live in a simulation?

@Marriott I can't speak for philosophy, but I agree that endless discussions about God are a colossal waste of time.

@MarcoOcram - "seems to have been running for more than thirteen billion years" - This is only if Creators are completely brainless. Otherwise, they would figure out that to draw some dots in the sky (with appropriate redshift) you need only one second.

I have no idea what you mean. Please elaborate.

@MarcoOcram - You make an impression as you never saw a computer game in your life and don't know that a computer game can be stopped, restarted from any point, replayed, rolled back. And all these actions will be completely transparent for the characters in the game.

I see. So where is your evidence for our living in a computer game?

@MarcoOcram - to start with, you could try this introduction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0KHiiTtt4w  Quantum Physics has the most compelling evidence so far. For decades, scientists have struggled to explain why consistent results with experiments on sub-particles only exist during experiments (not when scientists are not looking).

Computer games render on the screen only what you need to see at the moment. It does not have to render the whole history of the universe for the last 13 billion years. And each player has a local copy of the data on their device, just enough information to be able to render a snapshot of the universe.

I see. So do we all have our own personal rendered view? Are you part of my simulated view or are you real?

@MarcoOcram - Good question. As with any digital reality, all kinds of optimizations are possible. Some people say that the 7 billion population is fiction and there are only 3-4 hundred thousand active threads. Everything else is soft copies.
